# Matlab script should output to file and to the console

Tags: matlab, printf, output

What is the best way to save the output of a MATLAB script to a file AND output it to the console? I do not want to use diary b/c sometimes I try things out between script runs. Right now I use `fprintf` to output either to the console or to a log file. Can I do both without writing the same `fprintf` for both outputs?

Comment: Not sure if this would help to sort out your problem, but just curious what OS are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be in the wrong direction, but suppose you want to output something to the console, and save it, here is what you could do:

```
s = 'abcd'; %The thing you want to show and save

s           % Just show it
save s      % Save it to file
```

If however, you need a specific output that only comes from the print command. Here is what I would do:

1. Print to a variable
2. Save that variable
3. Show that variable

This way you only need the print once.

If that also does not work out for you, you could try to write a function where you do the print, at least then you can avoid code duplication.

Comment: I only need the log output, so I guess I will use the print function. For some reason I have not thought of that ^_^